# What visa do I need for a flight connection in Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia?

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, malaysia, kul

I am really confused. I have two separate tickets, both with AirAsia. 
First flight is Bombay to Kuala Lumpur, 2.5 hour layover, and connection to the second flight, Kuala Lumpur to Manila.

I believe that when I arrive in Kuala Lumpur, I have to go through immigration to collect my luggage, and go back to immigration to check in my next flight.

In that case, I will need a visa. When I go to [Immigration Department of Malaysia website](https://www.windowmalaysia.my/evisa/evisa.jsp) to apply for an e-Visa, it asks for accommodation proof, bank statement and Malaysia address, none of which I have.

**I am Indian and having Indian Passport**

Another search gave information regarding [transit visas](http://www.kln.gov.my/web/aus_perth/other_information/-/asset_publisher/2TQe/content/transit-pass?redirect=%2Fweb%2Faus_perth%2Fother_information), but doesn’t say whether I get it at the airport or the local embassy.

**Update:** To avoid any issue while travelling, I obtained a Transit Visa from local Malaysian Embassy in Kuwait.

Comment: We can't help you unless you tell us what country's passport you're traveling with.

Comment: Please add your nationality, to help provide an answer. Did you [look at AirAsia](https://www.airasia.com/ot/en/latest-news/malaysia-entry-requirement.page) info to make sure you need a visa? Also, KL has a sterile transit area, meaning you may be able to stay airside. Are you sure your bags won't be checked through?

Comment: I am Indian and have Indian passport

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid any issue while travelling, I made Transit Visa in local Malaysian embassy

**@@Update@@**

I already traveled, So I can give more proper update.

When I was check-in my luggage at Mumbai international airport I requested ground handling staff to check-in my luggage for Manila flight too and they agreed. They put 3 tag on my luggage

1. First Mumbai to Kuala Lumpur tag then
2. Transfer tag and lastly
3. Kuala Lumpur to Manila tag.

I was safe that time as I got two boarding pass at same time.
But unexpected thing happened, my Mumbai flight was late 1 hour for departure due to bad weather and got more late 3 hours.

When I reach Kuala Lumpur I was having only 5 minutes to catch Manila flight but as it was airline mistake they make Manila flight 1 hour late.

They cover 1 hour in Manila flight, but when I reach Manila airport at 13:30, my luggage was missing. When I ask AirAsia luggage security about it, they inform me that my luggage will come at 15:00, but I had to catch domestic flight from another airport at 15:25 and airport was 30-45 min away from international airport so they suggested me that I should carry on to domestic airport other wise I will miss my flight and they will send my luggage to onward station. Next day I call them to check if they send my luggage. They inform me that luggage was already sent same night. 
I went there to pick my luggage without any issue

Hope this can help someone

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know for the future: as stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&selDest=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20destination%28s%29%20above&TR=MY&selTrans=Malaysia&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by Airlines, there are two Arrangements for visa-free Transit by Indians:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, **except** for Holders of onward tickets for a max.
>   transit time of 24 hours, arriving at and
>   departing from Kuala Lumpur (KUL)

TWOV requires the trip to be in a single booking, so not applicable to you.

The second Arrangement, which **does** let you clear Immigration and **can** be used with separate tickets:

> Visa required, **except** for Holders of a valid visa issued by
>   Australia, China (People's Rep.), Chinese Taipei, Japan, Korea
>   (Rep.), New Zealand or USA to nationals of India residing in
>   country of nationality holding confirmed onward tickets for a
>   max. transit time of 120 hours, arriving at and
>   departing from Kuala Lumpur (KUL) on Malaysia Airlines (MH) or
>   Air Asia (AK). When transit time is longer than 8 hours it is
>   permitted to leave the transit area.

So if you have a valid visa from one of the mentioned countries, **and** the Connection time is at least 8 hours, you do **not** Need a visa.

Otherwise, you did the correct Thing by getting a Transit visa